# New Hard Drive, New File System

Tags: filesystem

I am putting a new hard drive in an old computer and I want to know the best file system to use for installing Ubuntu 13. I am going to install from a USB drive and I have "ISO to USB" software; the choices are FAT, FAT32, exFAT, and NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has got ext4 even if you boot it from USB drive. The software will only write the existing iso to your USB, you don't need to set up fs beforehand, it will be fat if that was the question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which FS you use when putting the iso on the USB drive, the best advice would be to follow the instructions on the ubuntu download page. (sorry, can't link, blame stack exchange)

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions on: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop 
On the right under "**Help with installing Ubuntu**" and everything should be ok.